# compare multiple means against hypothesized mean

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I've got three distributions that I've compared with each other, but I'd also like to test them against a hypothesized value of 1. I can just do multiple one-sample t-tests, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: how do you get that hypothesized mean? is it calculated from a distribution that you have at your hand?

Comment: The hypothesised mean is a "relative fitness of 1" - I've got fitness distributions for my treatments I'd like to ask "are these different from 1?". So normally I'd just do one-sample t-tests for each treatment, but I wondered whether there was a better way.